# How to count number of lines and words in a SharePoint online Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell-script

I am requested to generate a report that illustrates the number of pages and plus the count of words on each page, and the number of files in that site (word, PDF, images..etc.).

Is there any custom tool that i can use to enter my SharePoint site URL and then it will generate me the report i'm looking for Or if you think SharePoint Powershell can help with this, please share your ideas with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the below script and do customization to fit into your requirement:

```
<#

 NAME

   Get-SPOInventory



 DESCRIPTION

   Script to inventory all sites within a SharePoint Online (O365) site collection.

   If running this script on a machine that does not have SharePoint bits installed, you will need to install the latest SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK on the machine.   

   It can be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585     



 PARAMETER SiteUrl

   The URL of your SharePoint Online site collection



 PARAMETER UserName

   SharePoint Online User with FULL CONTROL permissions



 PARAMETER Password

   User password



 PARAMETER OutputFile

   The absolute folder path and file name where the site collection inventory file (*.csv) should be saved



 USAGE

   .\Get-SPOInventory.ps1 -SiteUrl https://rightpoint.sharepoint.com -UserName kkakanur@rightpoint.com -Password pass@word  -OutputFile C:\Rightpoint\SiteInventory.csv   



#>





[CmdletBinding()]

Param(

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

    [string]$SiteUrl,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

    [string]$UserName,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

    [string]$Password,

    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]

    [string]$OutputFile

)

BEGIN{

function Get-SPOSites{

        Param(

        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,

        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$RootWeb)





        #Create array variable to store data

        $siteitems = $null

        $siteitems = @()



        #get all webs under root web

        $Webs = $RootWeb.Webs

        $Context.Load($Webs)

        $Context.ExecuteQuery()



        #loop through the webs

        ForEach ($sWeb in $Webs)

        {

            Write-Host $sWeb.url



            $siteUrl = $sWeb.Url;



            #get all lists in web

            $AllLists = $sWeb.Lists

            $Context.Load($AllLists)

            $Context.ExecuteQuery()



            #loop through all lists in web

            ForEach ($list in $AllLists){

             Write-Host List: $list.Title

              #get list title

              $listTitle = $list.Title;



              # Do not inventory the following lists -> User Information List, Workflow History, Images, Site Assets, Composed Looks, Microfeed, Workflow Tasks, Access Requests, Master Page Gallery, Web Part Gallery, Style Library, List Template Library

              # NOTE: Add to (or remove from) the list below, as needed.



              If($listTitle -ne 'User Information List' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Workflow History' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Images' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Site Assets' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Composed Looks' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Microfeed' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Workflow Tasks' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Access Requests' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Master Page Gallery' -and  `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Web Part Gallery' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'Style Library' -and `

                 $listTitle -ne 'List Template Library') {







                 #Create a CAML Query object

                 #You can pass an undefined CamlQuery object to return all items from the list, or use the ViewXml property to define a CAML query and return items that meet specific criteria - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection0

                 #In this script an undefined CamlQuery object is passed, to get all list items 

                 $camlQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery





                 $AllItems = $list.GetItems($camlQuery)

                 $Context.Load($AllItems)

                 $Context.ExecuteQuery()



                 If($AllItems.Count -gt 0) {



                 ForEach ($item in $AllItems){



                          $listType = $list.BaseTemplate

                          $listUrl = $item["FileDirRef"]



                          #set item title based on the type of list

                          switch ($listType) 

                           { 

                                101 { $itemTitle = $item["FileLeafRef"] }    #Document Library

                                103 { $itemTitle = $item["FileLeafRef"] }    #Links List

                                109 { $itemTitle = $item["FileLeafRef"] }    #Picture Library

                                119 { $itemTitle = $item["FileLeafRef"] }    #Site Pages

                                851 { $itemTitle = $item["FileLeafRef"] }    #Media

                                default { $itemTitle = $item["Title"] }

                           }



                           Write-Host Item Name: $itemTitle



                          #retrieve item values

                          $itemType = $item.FileSystemObjectType

                          $itemurl = $item["FileRef"]

                          $itemCreatedBy = $item["Author"].LookupValue

                          $itemCreated = $item["Created"]

                          $itemModifiedBy = $item["Editor"].LookupValue

                          $itemModified = $item["Modified"]



                          #store the item values

                          #earlier versions (v2) of PowerShell do not support [Ordered]. If so, remove [Ordered]. Columns will be randomly ordered, but can be rearranged manually in the CSV file

                          $props = [Ordered]@{'Site' = $siteUrl;

                                     'List Title' = $listTitle;

                                     'List URL' = $listUrl;

                                     'List Type' = $listType;

                                     'Item Title' = $itemTitle;

                                     'Item URL' = $itemUrl;

                                     'Item Type' = $itemType;

                                     'Created By' = $itemCreatedBy;

                                     'Created'= $itemCreated;

                                     'Modified By' = $itemModifiedBy;

                                     'Modified' = $itemModified} ;                      



                          #append the values to the existing array object 

                          $siteitemarray = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props ; $siteitems += $siteitemarray



                   } #end loop for all items in list



                 } #check if item count is > 0



            } #check if it is a 'do not inventory' list          





          } #end loop for all lists in site 



          Get-SPOSites -RootWeb $sWeb -Context $Context #recursive call          



        } #end loop for all sites in site collection     



    #Output site collection inventory to CSV 

    $siteitems | Export-Csv $OutputFile -Append  

    }



    #reference the SharePoint Client DLLs

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" | Out-Null

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" | Out-Null    

}

PROCESS{



    #pass SharePoint Online credentials to get ClientContext object

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $PassWord -AsPlainText -Force

    $spoCred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)

    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)



    $ctx.Credentials = $spoCred



    $Web = $ctx.Web

    $ctx.Load($Web)

    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()    



    #call the function that does the inventory of the site collection

    Get-SPOSites -RootWeb $Web -Context $ctx



    #Inventory complete

    Write-Host Site Collection Inventory Completed! -foregroundcolor yellow ; 

}
```

More on the above script:

[How To Inventory Site Collections in SharePoint Online Using PowerShell and CSOM](https://www.rightpoint.com/thought/2016/02/11/how-to-inventory-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell-and-csom)

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to identify how many words there are on a page in SharePoint. What if you have list web part on the page? Also do you only need to count the number in the Site Page library or all .aspx files?

You might want to consider 3-rd party tools since it is likely not possible using PowerShell.

For the last requirement, here’s a PowerShell script to get all documents Inventory in a SharePoint site.

Please see the refence below:

[SharePoint Online: Get All Documents Inventory in a Site using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-get-all-documents-using-powershell.html#ixzz67gNT6swv)